# Writing a java program to send emails automatically on a timer

Tags: java, eclipse, timer

I would like to write a program that sends an automated email based on a timer that runs constantly. I would then like to somehow export this program from eclipse to a computer that does not run the ide, and run it constantly in the background. I have figured out the code to send emails through java, my question is more regarding how to export this project as an application (or something) that can be run on any computer without running it through the eclipse IDE.

Any help, or directions to a better a resource to learn from, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not asking for you to write me code, but rather for someone to explain the best method to export a project so that it can be run on any computer constantly.

Comment: share with us wherever you have tried so far, so that we can understand what approach u have followed..

Comment: Hi Arin,
I have a working program that sends an email through the eclipse IDE when i hit run. But now I would like to run this program on my work computer without installing eclipse and keeping it running constantly. How do i turn it into an application?

Comment: By the way, asking for a resource recommendation is off topic

Comment: Sorry santiago, this is my first time asking a question on this site. I guess I do not fully understand the rules or guidelines yet.

Comment: U need a scheduler/batch job which runs on every seconds to execute ur program.

Comment: Read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I don't think it can be a batch job because the emails need to be sent at a precise time and cannot wait in a queue. Unless my understanding of batch jobs is incorrect.

Comment: @Zane - your understanding >>is<< incorrect.  Please follow Arin's lead.  Hint Quartz,

Comment: If you know how to create a program that runs in Eclipse, you should be able to package it as a JAR (see Stephen C's answer below) which should run on any machine where Java is already installed. The other part of your question involving the scheduled operation of the program should also have answers somewhere on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple (manual) approach to turning a Java program into something that runs outside Eclipse:

- Create a runnable JAR following the instructions here: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm.

  If your application depends on library methods that are not part of the Java SE library, pay particular attention to the "select library handling strategy" step.
- Run the application from the command line as follows:

  ```
  $ java -jar yourapp.jar arguments ....
  ```

Obviously, you need at least a Java JRE installation on the execution platform to run `java`, and you should have configured your system (the $PATH or %PATH% environment variable) so that typing `java` runs the correct thing.

If you are using a build system like Maven, Ant, Gradle and so on, you can automate the step that generates the JAR.  (In fact, you can automate the entire build ... and break your dependency on any IDE.)

I **DO NOT** recommend trying to create an "executable" for your Java application.  For a start, executables cannot be run on any computer.  They can only be run on computers running a specific operating system / OS family.  A second problem is that you are effectively embedding a JRE in your application.  That makes applying the latest Java security patches difficult.

---

As for the problems of keeping the application running "constantly" and sending emails at specific times, that is just Java programming.

- Use Timer & TimerTask - e.g. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-run-a-task-periodically-in-java/
- Use a job scheduler.  For instance Quartz has an easy to use API for running jobs on a fixed schedule:  http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06

Comment: Great suggestion in Quartz, definitely worth exploring.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a runnable executable.  You can do this by following these steps: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse

Regarding the timer/scheduler, you may consider using Windows Task Scheduler (on Windows platform) or cron (*nix platform).

You will probably need to provide more information about the requirements you have for the timer in order to get a more specific answer there.

Comment: Great this gives me a good first step to tackle this problem. Thank you so much.